# Receiving and Processing a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, codeigniter

I have asked this question twice, with no satisfactory answer, that is, the problem I faced two questions ago still remains and none the wiser as how I am going to proceed with this.

This time I will provide all the code and what I receive, plus where the problem is occurring, I know what the issue is but since I'm relatively new to using AJAX it has me puzzled.

I have a form, which when you click the second to last field, duplicates itself, with the help of another user all the id's get changed to be unique.

```
<form role="form" class="batchinvoice form-horizontal" id="batchinvoice">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="sl_propid" >
                                        <?php foreach($property as $row) :?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $row[ 'property_name'] . " " . $row[ 'property_address1']; ?>
                                        </option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                    <input type="text" name="sl_date" placeholder="Date" class="sl_date form-control" id="datepicker">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="sl_ref" placeholder="Invoice Reference" class="form-control" id="sl_ref">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="sl_nom_id" id="sl_nom_id">
                                        <?php foreach($subitem_nominals as $row) :?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['subnom_id']; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $row[ 'nom_subitem_name']; ?>
                                        </option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="sl_desc" id="sl_desc" placeholder="Invoice Description" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="sl_vat" placeholder="VAT Amount" class="vat form-control" id="vat">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                    <input type="text" name="sl_net" placeholder="Net" class="form-control" id="sl_net">
                                </div>
                        </form>
```

The JS for the form clone

```
<script>
var clone_iterator = 0;
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
    $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd");
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();



    $('#batchinvoice .vat').click(function () {
       // alert("ok");
        var id = "batchinvoice" + clone_iterator;
        $('#batchinvoice').clone(true).attr("name", id).attr('id', id).appendTo(".panel-body"); // here I added this .attr('id',id)
        // here we'll change the id's of all the elements who actualy have an attribute

        $('#' + id + ' *[id]').each(function () {

            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + clone_iterator); //we set the attribute id
        });
        clone_iterator++;
    });



    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var res = {};
        console.log(res);
        $('.batchinvoice').each(function (i) { //the class is a good use to do things like that you can repeat it more than once !
            res[i] = new Array();
            console.log(res);
                     res[i].propid = $(this).find('*[name=sl_propid]').val();
            res[i].date = $(this).find('.sl_date formcontrol').val();
            res[i].ref = $(this).find('*[name=sl_ref]').val();
            res[i].id = $(this).find('*[name=sl_nom_id]').val();
            res[i].desc = $(this).find('*[name=sl_desc]').val();
            res[i].vat = $(this).find('*[name=sl_vat]').val();
            res[i].net = $(this).find('*[name=sl_net]').val();
            console.log(res);
            alert(res[i].propid);

            // i++;   
            //$.each('',function( index, value ){}
            //(int)i is already incremented if you use class and not IDS

        });
        console.log(res);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>FinancialInput/addInvoiceToLedger',
            data: res,
            sucess: function (e) {
                alert(e);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e.toString());
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

This is the particular controller function in CodeIgniter, Note I have tried multiple things.

```
function addInvoiceToLedger(){
    // $this->load->model('SalesLedgerModel');
    // $propid = $this->input->post('propid');
    // print_r($this->input->post());
    // $date = $this->input->post('date');
    // $ref = $this->input->post('ref');
    // $nomid = $this->input->post('id');
    // $desc = $this->input->post('desc');
    // $vat = $this->input->post('vat');
    // $net = $this->input->post('net');

    $res = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);

    //problem is probably here, it's

    //for($x = 0; $x < count($res); $x++){


    foreach($res as $row){

    $this->SalesLedgerModel->addInvoiceToLedger($row.propid, $row.date, $row.ref, $row.nomid, $row.desc, $row.vat, $row.net);

    }
    //}


    //redirect('home/financial_input/');
}
```

the Model Function

```
function addInvoiceToLedger($propid, $date, $ref, $nomid, $desc, $vat, $net){

    $data = array('sl_prop_id' => $propid, 'sl_date' => $date,
        'sl_ref' => $ref, 'sl_nominal_sub' => $nomid, 'sl_invoice_desc' => $desc, 'sl_vat' => $vat, 'sl_amount' => $net);

    $this->db->insert_batch('salesledger', $data);
}
```

[image: FireBug with the Arrays] 
[image: Objects Content]

Which all have the relevant field data for each form inside them.

My question is how do I receive and handle the array? Every loop I've tried doesn't work, **I've tried getting variables singularly**(as you can see above commented out) but that doesn't make sense (or work) because in the $.ajax data it is set to **res**, but $this->input->post('res') doesn't return anything nor does $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE)

Majorly stuck, I feel this should be a simple thing, **but I clearly don't understand it.**

Edit, still same problem can't find an answer anywhere D:, tried many things.

Still the same problem "res" is sent as post, but I can't retrieve it in the controller with $this->input->post()...anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to submit a comment but apparently I need 50 rep for that so I'll take my chances with an answer.

In your $.ajax block what if you change the data section to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>FinancialInput/addInvoiceToLedger',
    data: { res : res },
    sucess: function (e) {
        alert(e);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: That's what it should be but, it isn't let me check if that's the issue, if that fixes it, I'll first thank you then go punch myself haha.

Comment: It's still returning invalid argument in the foreachloop, aka res isn't set to anything.